# If webpack tree-shaking handle node_modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollupjs, tree-shaking

I am working on node@6.11.0, webpack@3.4.1

### file.js

```
export function foo () {
  return 'foo'
}

export function bar() {
  return 'bar'
}
```

### main.js

```
import { foo } from './file'
import { log } from 'mathjs'
foo()
log(10000,10)
```

And bundle.js include all methods from math.js, so i wonder if tree-shaking works.
and the function bar has signed with `/* unused harmony export bar */`
when i use tree-shaking, the bundlejs should be only include foo and lod methods, shouldn't it?
`git clone https://github.com/z2014/All-test-demo`,and test

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And bundle.js include all methods from math.js, so i wonder if tree-shaking works.

Comment: Please update the question with more details

Answer (score 1):

Unused code is removed by a minifier (such as UglifyJS). Tree-shaking just makes it possible for minifier to remove it.

So, in your case, enabling UglifyJS will most likely solve the problem.

You can read more about this behavior in
https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking, https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/harmony-unused and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2866

Comment: but when i use UglifyJS plugin ,i got  1571 KIB, and when i don't use tree-shaking, it also got 1573 KIB, so i wonder if tree-shaking works

Comment: I have no idea about your problem because I have no code here, but I think you can try to find whether your unused code in your build. 

PS: Remember to run webpack with flag `-p` for production build.

Comment: One more question: What function do you want to remove from build? Tree shaking only works with es module not normal commonjs package (what you install by npm). I see you use `babel-preset-es2015`, it will transform all es module to normal commonjs so tree-shaking won't work

Comment: i use it to compare with `presets: [['es2015', {modules:false}], 'stage-3', 'react']`

Comment: preset es2015 doesn't have option `modules: false`. You should my new MR

Comment: but when i set `modules: false`, it does tree-shaking